# Why is the event $\left \{\omega \in \Omega\ \bigg |\ \sum\limits_{n \geq 1} X_n (\omega) \lt \infty \right \}$ considered to be a tail event?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots$ be a sequence of independent random variables in a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P).$ Then why is the event $\left \{\omega \in \Omega\ \bigg |\ \sum\limits_{n \geq 1} X_n (\omega) \lt \infty \right \}$ considered to be a tail event?

Let $\mathcal F_n' = \sigma \left (X_n, X_{n+1}, \cdots \right ).$ Then $X_n$ is $\mathcal F_n$-measurable and so is $\mathcal F_n'$-measurable. Now for any $m \geq n,$ the random variable $X_m$ is $\mathcal F_m'$-measurable and hence $\mathcal F_n'$-measurable as well, as $\mathcal F_m' \subseteq \mathcal F_n'$ for all $m \geq n.$ I don't know how to argue it from here? I think that I need to use independence of $X_n$ someway here.

Any help would be warmly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Presumably the intuition is that $\sum\limits_{n \geq 1} X_n (\omega) \lt \infty$ is equivalent to $\sum\limits_{n \geq k} X_n (\omega) \lt \infty$ for any $k$

Comment: @Henry$:$ Yes that's what I initially thought but I would like to make it rigorous which I am not able to do. Why is independence important here?

Comment: I imagine independence is needed here to apply Kolmogorov's $0-1$ law. Otherwise the result you stated is valid without assuming independence.

Comment: @Michh$:$ Nice remark. You are absolutely right. Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{\infty} X_i (\omega) \lt \infty$ for some $\omega \in \Omega$ if and only if for any $n \in \mathbb N$ the infinite sum $\sum\limits_{i=n}^{\infty} X_i (\omega) \lt \infty.$ So we have $$A : =\left \{\omega \in \Omega\ \bigg |\ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i (\omega) \lt \infty \right \} = \left \{\omega \in \Omega\ \bigg |\ \sum\limits_{i=n}^{\infty} X_i (\omega) \lt \infty \right \} = : A_n$$ for all $n \in \mathbb N.$ Now fix some $p \in \mathbb N.$ Then $X_i \in \mathcal F_p'$ for all $i \geq p$ and consequently the random variable $X_{p,N} : =\sum\limits_{i = p}^{N} X_i$ is $\mathcal F_p'$-measurable for all $N \geq p.$ Thus we have $$\begin{align*} A_p & =  \left \{\omega \in \Omega\ \bigg |\ \lim\limits_{N \to \infty} X_{p,N} (\omega) \lt \infty \right \} \\ & = \bigcap\limits_{j = 1}^{\infty}\ \bigcup\limits_{k=p}^{\infty}\ \bigcap\limits_{(l,m) \in \mathbb N_{k}^2} \left \{\omega \in \Omega\ \bigg |\ \left \lvert X_{p,l} (\omega) - X_{p,m} (\omega) \right \rvert \lt \frac {1} {j} \right \}  \end{align*}$$ where $\mathbb N_{k} : = \{k,k+1,k+2, \cdots \} \subseteq \mathbb N.$ Thus $A_p \in \mathcal F_p'$ and hence $A \in \mathcal F_p'.$ Since $p \in \mathbb N$ were arbitrary it follows that $A \in \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal F_n' = \mathcal T.$ $\square$

Answer (score 0):

- $X_n, \dots, X_N$ are $\mathcal F_n'$-measurable.
- $\sum_{i=n}^N X_i$ is $\mathcal F_n'$-measurable.
- The pointwise limit of the sequence of partial sums is $\mathcal F_n'$-measurable.
- Circle back and deal with $X_1, \dots, X_{n-1}$, if desired.

If you are still confused, there and other questions and answers that discuss this type of thing.

Comment: In the third point do you mean that $\left \{\omega \in \Omega\ \bigg |\ \lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \sum\limits_{i=n}^{N} X_n (\omega) \lt \infty \right \}$ is $\mathcal F_n'$-measurable. If yes, then this is the only non-trivial part which immediately concludes the required result.

Comment: We can describe the above set in the following manner. $$\left \{\omega \in \Omega\ \bigg |\ \lim\limits_{N \to \infty}  \sum\limits_{i = n}^{N} X_i (\omega) \lt \infty \right \} = \left \{\omega \in \Omega\ \bigg |\ \limsup\limits_{N \to \infty}  \sum\limits_{i = n}^{N} X_i (\omega) = \liminf\limits_{N \to \infty}  \sum\limits_{i = n}^{N} X_i (\omega) \right \}$$ The latter event can easily seen to be $\mathcal F_n'$-measurable.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was a bit confused. I think if you can show that the lim sup and lim inf are measurable, and then intersect with the set where they are equal, then I think you are done. (Sorry, on my phone)

Comment: $:$ Could you please check my last comment?

Comment: So the brief reasoning is the following $:$ $$\left \{\omega \in \Omega\ \bigg |\ \lim\limits_{N \to \infty}  \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{N} X_i (\omega) \lt \infty \right \} = \bigcap\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty}  \left \{\omega \in \Omega\ \bigg |\ \lim\limits_{N \to \infty}  \sum\limits_{i = n}^{N} X_i (\omega) \lt \infty \right \} \subseteq \bigcap\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mathcal F_n' = \mathcal T.$$

Comment: Regarding prior comment, I think you still need to ensure the lim sup and lim inf are finite, right? They could be equal and infinite

Comment: $:$ Measurable functions could potentially take values in the extended real line $\overline {\mathbb R}$ where $-\infty,\infty$ are considered as points. Does it create any problem as such?

Comment: I thought you wanted a finite limit for the series?

Comment: Yes I wanted that but then I could have modified it in a way where limsup and liminf are contained to $[-n,n]$ and then take the union over all such $n.$

Comment: Good catch. I think then we would have encountered a situation like $\infty - \infty.$ Is there any way to overcome that? I think I am very close.

Comment: I just want to say, I may delete my answer and write a new one later. I don't think my original answer is good. I think the lim sup, lim inf idea is better.

Comment: Please don't delete your answer. Rather I would suggest you to edit your answer accordingly (if possible).

Comment: Could you please check my answer?